# Sending XMLHttpRequest (JavaScript), Getting Response Status 12002 (IE only)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tomcat, xmlhttprequest, connection-timeout

I am facing a problem with an asynchronous request in JavaScript - but only within Internet Explorer. We are using Apache Tomcat 6.0.18, Java 6.0.11, IE 8, IE 10 (don't ask yourself - it's a customers infrastructure, but i'm having the same issues with Tomcat 8 as well).

Behind the scenes: There is a server application (Java) which starts to generate a file as soon as the request is sent by the client (Java Script). For most cases it takes just some minutes (< 5min) to generate the requested file, BUT there is another case: A huge Zip - 21MB - takes more than an hour to create.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', pathprefix + "/ssi/" + paramArea + "_suchfunction.html?" + command + "=true", true);
    //Trigger the file generation process
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        try{
                            if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
                                if ((xhr.status == 200) || (xhr.status == 0)) {
    //wait until ready, get the file as a downloadable
```

So far, no problem. The code above works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. BUT guess what, IE behaves differently (surprise surprise).
After one hour i get a timeout error (xhr.status = 12002).

I have researched a lot. Unfortunately i haven't found any working suggestions. This is what i've tried so far:

- Setting the timeout of XMLHttpRequest(); explicably to infinite
  (xhr.timeout = 0;)
- Setting the Timeout of the Tomcat Server in web.xml and server.xml
- Request-Header "Connection: Keep-Alive"

This is the official statement of Microsoft for it:
 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181050

Do you guys have any other suggestions. What else could i try? 
I am aware, that 1 hour+ of processing is a lot, but for now, i don't want to redesign the functionality.

Thanks for further suggestions.

Comment: This should be implemented with the long-polling at least. It is hard to go against browser limitations and could be impossible to bypass them all. Also, worth to keep in mind, that if you will ever run this application in real networks, proxy boxes may drop your connections.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try to figure out another solution to this case.